# Knockout.js - How bind a data-var in a foreach

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I would like to bind `data-id` to my looped items in knockout

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="attr: {data-id: $data.id}">
            <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
            <img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: $data.img}">
            <h4>Volkswagen.co.uk</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

`<li data-bind="attr: {data-id: $data.id}">` So specifically this line of code is what I would like to get working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `data-id` is not a legal identifier name in JavaScript you need to write:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'data-id' : $data.id}">
```

See attr binding documentation [Applying attributes whose names aren’t legal JavaScript variable names](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) section.